# MSB3481 Certificate Error

Tags: windows, msbuild, certificate

I have a build server on window 2008 R2. I am running CruiseControl.net using msbuil 3.5. I know for a fact that the certificate is installed and the thumbprint is correct. I did look into this SO question [MSBuild SignFile task returning MSB3481: The signing certificate could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409465/msbuild-signfile-task-returning-msb3481-the-signing-certificate-could-not-be-lo) and tried that solution but didn't work. From the msbuild script the error is thrown on the code line below. I am not sure if there is anything specific to window 2008 R2.

```
<SignFile CertificateThumbprint="$(CertThumbprint)"
 SigningTarget="@(%(ManifestItems.DeployManifestOutput))"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out during the install for the original pfx certificate file on window 2008 R2, one of the values default to prompt for password. In my scenario the original pfx certificate file doesn't have a password but windows still prompt for a password entry. During the MSBuild execution on the build server the password prompt, which causes it to hang since no response to the prompt is made.

A few ways to go about this is to supply an empty password through the assembly manifest in MSBuild script or during the pfx certificate install to opt out to prompt for password.